# COUNT Data from the past 7 days, but have it so it shows the result for each day in those 7 days

Tags: php, mysql

I don't really know how to explain it, but I have a Morris.JS chart in my Web appliication and I want to have the ability to get data from the last 7 days and put it into the chart.

I don't know if using DATE formats work in a Query nor do I know how to do it, so I'm here asking for assistance on it.

My columns are `x` as the value and `datetime` as the datetime and I don't know how I would get the value of X for each day for 7 days.

Hopefully this makes sense?

Comment: *I don't know if using DATE formats work in a Query nor do I know how to do it.*...is Google not available in your area? SO it not a tutorial site but a troubleshooting one. Please make an earnest attempt and come back with issues.

Comment: The thing is, none of it makes sense for me personally.... I'm using to selecting columns from a table and that, what I'm building is a huge learning curve for me and I need all the help I can get. I apologize, but it's hard to make an attempt when I barely understand how it's even done :P

Answer (score 0):

Select, date add,  group by date.

```
 SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(my_date, - INTERVAL 7 DAY)), my_data, other_data from TABLE_NAMER group by  DATE(DATE_ADD(my_date, - INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```